# How to create a facebook like dropdown menu using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I just wanna know how I can create a Facebook-like drop-down menu using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a dropdown menu that is coded to show the menu when your mouse hovers over it.
The first part is the Html then the Next is the CSS
If you want images you could add an extra class for that

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-items">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>





 /* the css*/


/* this is Dropdown Button */
    .dropbuttton {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;   /* size varies */
      font-size: 16px; /* size varies */
      border: none;
    }

    /* The container for positioning the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by until mouse hovers) */
    .dropdown-items {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-items a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
```